# Copy Named Range cell values with line breaks into html/email body

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy the named range cell `messageHeader` into a HTML template to send an email.

The cell looks like this in Google Sheets:

[image: Google Sheets view]

The console also displays it correctly:

[image]

However, as soon as the HTML template processes this named range value, it flattens all line breakers in cell into a single line, and the email arrives like this.

[image]

The code:

```
const messageHeader = wsS.getRange("messageHeader").getValue()
```

HTML template code:

```
<div class="main"><?= messageHeader ?></div>
```

How can I copy line breaks into HTML teamplate that will show up correctly in the email?
HTML has `<br>` for line breaks, but I have no idea how to implement this.
Adding `<br>` in the cell still goes out as plain text in the email instead of new line.

Comment: I thought that in your script, how about modiyfing to `const messageHeader = wsS.getRange("messageHeader").getValue().replace(/\n/g, "<br>")`?

Comment: This shows in my email in a single line again with the plain text `Hi All,<br><br>Please find below the latest summary ...`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your reply, I noticed that your script has 2 modification points. When I saw your script for the first time, I thought that your script has one modification point. I apologize for this. In your script, as one more modification point, please modify from `<div class="main"><?= messageHeader ?></div>` to `<div class="main"><?!= messageHeader ?></div>` and test it again.

Comment: Tanaike I managed to solve the problem with your first solution but instead of doing it on the .gs side I did this in the HTML template code `<div class="main"><?!= messageHeader.replace(/\n/g, "<br>") ?></div>`. Thank you!